# More than two columns amsmath cases

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath, cases

I'm trying to use the `cases` environment to show an arbitrary equation. But I noticed that it only allows me to use 2 columns. However, I would require a third column, or perhaps a fourth as well.

An example is shown below:

```
\begin{equation*}
  \Md_1 \Cup \Md_2=
  \begin{cases}
        \Md_2            & when \ \Md_1 = \nothing \\
        \Md_1            & when \ \Md_2 = \nothing \\
        \Md_1 \cup \Md_2 & otherwise
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
```

What I would like to write is something like this (this does not actually work):

```
\begin{equation*}
  \Md_1 \Cup \Md_2=
  \begin{cases}
        \Md_2            & when \ \Md_1 = \nothing & where & x = foo    \\
                         &                         &       & y = bar    \\
        \Md_1            & when \ \Md_2 = \nothing & where & z = notfoo \\
        \Md_1 \cup \Md_2 & otherwise               &       &            \\
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: Make your own either using a left right construction plus array or left right plus the aligned env

Comment: For text inside math mode, you should use `\text`.

Comment: daleif, could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would just use a `\phantom` to yield a similar alignment. Alternatively, make up your own `array` with the alignment you require:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  M_1 \cup M_2 =
  \begin{cases}
        M_2            & \text{when $M_1 = foo$} \\
                       & \text{\phantom{when }$M_2 = bar$} \\
        M_1            & \text{when $M_2 = baz$} \\
        M_1 \cup M_2   & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  M_1 \cup M_2 =
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \left\{\begin{array}{l @{\quad} l r l}
        M_2            & \text{when } & M_1 &{}= foo \\
                       &              & M_2 &{}= bar \\
        M_1            & \text{when } & M_2 &{}= baz \\
        M_1 \cup M_2   & \text{otherwise}
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The former may not work or be easy in general, but it works in your case. The latter should work in a more general setting.

Comment: How would I add the two extra columns (`where x = foo`)?

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer: You would add more elements in the `array` column specification. For example, `l @{\quad} l r l r l` would add another two columns - first is `r`ight-aligned and the second is `l`eft-aligned.

Comment: Thanks. I want to mark both answer as they are both correct but this one seems a little less messy to me (the latter). Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Using only amsmath package, the environement *aligned* allows you to use as many columns as you want :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        M_1 \cup M_2 =
            \begin{cases}
            \begin{aligned}
                M_2 & \text{ when } M_1 = 0 &\text{where } & x = f\\
                    &                       &              & y = b\\
                M_1 & \text{ when } M_2 = 0 &\text{where } & z = n\\
                M_1 \cup M_2 & \text{ otherwise }&         &      \\
            \end{aligned}
        \end{cases}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: result using amsmath aligned environment]

Comment: You could use `aligned` for just the "where" clauses

Answer (score 6):

I probably would find a different way to express my ideas. Anyway, here's a possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{mcases}[1][l]
 {\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \left\lbrace
  \def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \array{@{}l@{\quad}#1@{}}}
 {\endarray\right.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
M_1 \Cup M_2=
\begin{mcases}[ll@{\ }l]
  M_2          & \text{when $M_1 = \emptyset$} & \text{where} & x = f \\
               &                               &              & y = b \\
  M_1          & \text{when $M_2 = \emptyset$} & \text{where} & z = n \\
  M_1 \cup M_2 & \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\text{otherwise}}
\end{mcases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Without an optional argument, `mcases` is the same as `cases`. The optional argument should specify the column types after the first, which is fixed.

[image]