# Alignment in equation environment

Tags: math-mode, spacing, horizontal-alignment

I am not able to align equations within a curly bracket. My code is the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt, A4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
Consider the following:
\[
P\Big[\frac{1}{2}+\mu \Big ]=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l}
\displaystyle{0\hspace{1cm}\mathrm{if}\quad \mu <-\frac{1}{2}} \\ 
\displaystyle{\frac{1}{2}+\mu \hspace{0.3cm}\mathrm{if}\quad -\frac{1}{2}%
\leq \mu \leq \frac{1}{2}} \\ 
\displaystyle{1\hspace{1cm}\mathrm{if}\quad \mu >\frac{1}{2}}%
\end{array}
\right. 
\]
\end{document}
```

This produce the following:

[image]

As you may notice, the "if" are not aligned and so the "=" are. In addition, I would like to increase a little bit the space between rows to avoid that the "1" in the last fraction is "attached" to the "2" in the second raw. How can I fix this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use two columns in the array. Even better use the cases env, it already incluse a two column array and the brace (much cleaner code). And remove the hspace

Comment: If you want to force it into displaystyle, use the mathtools package, and its dcases env

Comment: @daleif. Thanks for your reply. I do not need to use displaystyle. I tried with cases, but apparently everything goes into a single row, rather than in 3.

Comment: Please update your code, you of course need ``\\`` to switch row, and `&` to switch columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that aligns three columns, adapted from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235104/55879).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Consider the following:
\[
P\Big[\frac{1}{2}+\mu \Big] =
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{l @{\quad} l r l}
    0            & \text{if } & \mu &{}< -\dfrac{1}{2}\\
    \dfrac{1}{2} & \text{if } & -\dfrac{1}{2} &{}< \mu < \dfrac{1}{2}\\
    1            & \text{if } & \mu &{}> \dfrac{1}{2}.
\end{array}
\right.\]
\end{document}
```

I made a couple simplifications: you can use `\dfrac` rather than carrying around `\displaystyle` all the time, and `\text` behaves better than `\mathrm` (though it does require you to use `amsmath`). The `\arraystretch` line sets the vertical spacing, preventing collisions.

[image]

Comment: This is even better! I will use this indeed, since it also align the ">" and "<" symbols.

Answer (score 8):

I'd forego the use of `\displaystyle`, setting the entire construction using [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `cases`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

Consider the following:
\[
  P\bigl[ \tfrac{1}{2} +\mu \bigr] = \begin{cases}
    0                   & \text{if }\mu <-\tfrac{1}{2} \\
    \tfrac{1}{2} + \mu  & \text{if }-\tfrac{1}{2} \leq \mu \leq \tfrac{1}{2} \\
    1                   & \text{if }\mu > \tfrac{1}{2}
  \end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

You can increase the gap between rows inside the `cases` environment using `\\[<len>]`, where you specify the length `<len>` (say `2\jot` or `20pt`, say).

Comment: Thanks I tried using cases env within an equation env and it worked.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution that uses the `dcases` environment provided by the `mathtools` package. It works like `cases`, except that all contents are rendered in `\displaystyle` automatically. The screenshot also shows the output of the corresponding `cases` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
Consider the following:
\[
P\Bigl[ \frac{1}{2}+\mu \Bigr]=
\begin{dcases} 
0               & \text{if}\quad\phantom{{-}\frac{1}{2}\leq{}}\mu <-\frac{1}{2} \\ 
\frac{1}{2}+\mu & \text{if}\quad{-}\frac{1}{2}\leq \mu \leq +\frac{1}{2} \\ 
1               & \text{if}\quad{+}\frac{1}{2}<\mu
\end{dcases} 
\]

\[
P\bigl[ \tfrac{1}{2}+\mu \bigr]=
\begin{cases} 
0               & \text{if}\quad\phantom{{-}\frac{1}{2}\leq{}}\mu <-\frac{1}{2} \\ 
\frac{1}{2}+\mu & \text{if}\quad{-}\frac{1}{2}\leq \mu \leq +\frac{1}{2} \\ 
1               & \text{if}\quad{+}\frac{1}{2}<\mu
\end{cases} 
\]
\end{document}
```